# Correctly pass a char array and char pointer to function by reference in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings

Is there a right way to call a char array and a char pointer to go to a function but it's pass by reference where it will also be manipulated?

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void manipulateStrings(char *string1, char *string2[])
{

    strcpy (string1, "Apple");
    strcpy (string2, "Banana");

    printf ("2 string1: %s", string1);
    printf ("2 string2: %s", &string2);

}


int main ()
{
    char *stringA;
    char stringB[1024];

    stringA = (char *) malloc ( 1024 + 1 );

    strcpy (stringA, "Alpha");
    strcpy (stringB, "Bravo");
    printf ("1 stringA: %s", stringA);
    printf ("1 stringB: %s", stringB);

    manipulateStrings(stringA, stringB);

    printf ("3 stringA: %s", stringA);
    printf ("3 stringB: %s", stringB);


    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure if I'm understanding correctly how to pass such variables to a function and change the values of those variables who happen to be char / strings

Edit: My question is - How would you be able to change the values of the two strings in the function?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Andrey - added an edit to clarify my question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no such thing as pass by reference in C.  Everything in C is passed by value. This leads to the solution you need; add another level of indirection.

However, your code has other problems.  You don't need to pass a pointer to pointer (or pointer to array) because you are not mutating the *input*, only what it refers to.  You want to copy a string. Great. All you need for that is a pointer to char initialized to point to a sufficient amount of memory.

In the future, if you need to mutate the input (i.e., assign a *new* value to it), then use a pointer to pointer.

```
int mutate(char **input) 
{
    assert(input);
    *input = malloc(some_size);
}

int main(void)
{
    /* p is an uninitialized pointer */
    char *p;
    mutate(&p);
    /* p now points to a valid chunk of memory */
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There most certainly is pass by reference in C. You do so with the & symbol prefixing the variable.

Comment: @SevenBits: No, there most certainly is *not*.  `&` is the address of operator.  Passing by reference is *not* the same as taking the address of soem variable.  I was wondering how long it would take for someone to come along and incorrectly equate adding another level of indirection to passing by reference.

Comment: I'm still trying to internalize this but is there a way where stringB can also be mutated in another function if it was declared like how I declared it?

Comment: @AisIceEyes: What it *refers* to can be mutated, but `stringB` cannot be unless you pass a pointer to *it*.  It's easier if you think of everything being passed by value (i.e., a copy, which it is).  You can't mutate the copy, but in this case, what you are passing (the value) is an address. So, you can still muck around with what lives at that address, but if you want to modify the inout itself, you will need to get *its* address. Note that, in this case, you have an array, so taking its address results in a pointer to array, not a pointer to pointer to char. You cannot modify arrays directly

Comment: @EdS. I have seen code, though, do things like `some_int = 7` where some_int was passed into the function with the & operator. Because this wrote to the memory that `some_int` is stored in I had always assumed it was similar to passing by reference.

Comment: @EdS.: Would it be alright if you show how to modify an array just somewhat like how I showed originally in my question? I am not sure how to do that or if it's even possible.

Comment: @SevenBits: No, it is different.  Take, for example, the method which receives the argument; `void whatever(int *p) { p = malloc(sizeof(int))`.  The change to `p` will not be visible to the caller because the function is only mutating its local copy.  That is not pass by reference; you are passing a pointer by value.  Of course, you can mutate what the pointer *refers* to by dereferencing it, but that is not what it means to pass something by reference.  C is pass by value only.

Comment: @AisIceEyes: In your question you are not modifying the array variable itself, only what it refers to (well, what the pointer it degrades to refers to, same thing).  You have to separate the variable (be it a pointer or an array) from what they refer to.

Comment: @EdS.: Thank you for enlightening me on that. I will keep that in mind for the future. Guess I was wrong. :(

Comment: The question was very clear. This answer is not (and I need an answer too). Lots of argument about the semantics of pass by reference etc. That's not relevant. What IS relevant is showing the OP (and anyone else coming from google, like me) how to do what he is trying to do. Ie: Modify a string that is somewhere else within a subroutine. It may be that the OP needs to make his/her variable declarations global. I'd find it very unlikely it can't be done. Would love to see someone answer the question properly but correcting the code and reposting it in their answer.

Comment: @user1863152: Except I show you exactly how to do that; you add another level of indirection, i.e., pointer to pointer in this case. It's literally the first paragraph. Define 'modify a string'. Modify the value of the string? Just pass a pointer to it. Modify the pointer? Add a level of indirection. It's perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently doing:

`manipulateStrings(stringA, stringB);`

And printing from within `manipulateStrings`. Instead, to verify you're doing it correctly, I would do:

```
manipulateStrings(stringA, stringB);
printf ("2 string1: %s", string1);
printf ("2 string2: %s", &string2);
```

And not print from within that function. That way, you can test if the variables are being copied by-value or by-reference.